# Bootstrap 2.3.2 conflict with Google Custom Search results box

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on the website for Apache HBase, and all of the CSS I'm going to talk about is on the live site at hbase.apache.org. I've implemented a Google Custom Search Engine in a Bootstrap 2.3.2 site, and for the most part it is working. There is one quirk that I see in Chrome and Safari IOS, but not in Safari or Firefox. In Chrome and Safari iOS9, the GCSE result box is truncated in height because its containing div gets a height set, rather than the height being set to auto. I was previously having this problem in other parts of the site, until I added this rule:

```
  .collapse.in {
      height: auto;
  }
```

The following screenshots are taken with the browser window the same size, on Chrome and then Safari:

[Chrome shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYrJN.png)

[Safari does not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8qZz.png)

I read the Bootstrap page about fixing conflicting CSS rules (getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-box-sizing), and tried to implement it by adding the following rule:

```
  input.gsc-input,
  .gsc-input-box,
  .gsc-input-box-hover,
  .gsc-input-box-focus,
  .gsc-search-button,
  .gsc-results-wrapper-visible {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
  }
```

Can anyone spot what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being caused by this in your "bootstrap-responsive.min.css"

```
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .nav-collapse {
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
  }
}
```

When your search results are visible, a class 'gsc-overflow-hidden' is added to the body, so use that in a selector to disable the transform property. To do that add this:

```
@media(max-width: 480px) {
    .gsc-overflow-hidden .nav-collapse {
        -webkit-transform: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. Thank you!